# Zend Framework: create url to other site

Tags: url, zend-framework, frameworks

I am new with Zend and i don't know how to generate url from text, eg. 'example.com' should be 'http://example.com/'. How to simply do this?

Comment: `<a href="http://<?= $url ?>">` ;)

Comment: @Volvox So, what if url will be http://example.com? I expect helper in Zend..

Comment: I don't recall any helper for such trivial task. URL helper helps create internal links using Zend routing, so it will not be good for external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `url` and a `serverUrl` helpers. See [initial helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial). Or you can [write a custom helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.custom).

#### serverUrl helper

```
serverUrl($requestUri = null)
```

Helper for returning the current server URL (optionally with request URI).

```
// Current server URL in the example is: http://www.example.com/foo.html

echo $this->serverUrl();
// Output: http://www.example.com

echo $this->serverUrl(true);
// Output: http://www.example.com/foo.html

echo $this->serverUrl('/foo/bar');
// Output: http://www.example.com/foo/bar

echo $this->serverUrl()->getHost();
// Output: www.example.com

echo $this->serverUrl()->getScheme();
// Output: http

$this->serverUrl()->setHost('www.foo.com');
$this->serverUrl()->setScheme('https');
echo $this->serverUrl();
// Output: https://www.foo.com
```

#### Url helper

```
url($urlOptions, $name, $reset, $encode)
```

Creates a URL string based on a named route. $urlOptions should be an associative array of key/value pairs used by the particular route.

```
// Using without options: (current request is: user/id/1)
echo $this->url();
// Output: user/info/id/1

// Set URL options:
echo $this->url(
    array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'info', 'username' => 'foobar')
);
// Output: user/info/username/foobar

// Using a route:
$router->addRoute(
    'user',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'user/:username',
        array(
            'controller' => 'user',
            'action'     => 'info',
        )
    )
);

echo $this->url(array('name' => 'foobar'), 'user');
// Output: user/foobar

// Using reset: (current request is: user/id/1)
echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'info'), null, false);
// Output: user/info/id/1

echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'info'), null, true);
// Output: user/info

// Using encode:
echo $this->url(
    array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'info', 'username' => 'John Doe'), null, true, false
);
// Output: user/info/username/John Doe

echo $this->url(
    array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'info', 'username' => 'John Doe'), null, true, false
);
// Output: user/info/username/John+Doe
```